# Pandas: Fill NaN values after Left Outer Join with values in another dateframe and with no common rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, fillna

Consider the two following dataframes:

df1:

```
time                       p_value       
2022-03-12 00:00:00+00:00  38743.7
2022-03-12 00:05:00+00:00    38802
2022-03-12 00:10:00+00:00    38842
2022-03-12 00:15:00+00:00  38865.9
2022-03-12 00:20:00+00:00  38882.1
2022-03-12 23:35:00+00:00    38965
2022-03-12 23:40:00+00:00  38933.2
2022-03-12 23:45:00+00:00  38878.4
2022-03-12 23:50:00+00:00  38861.3
2022-03-12 23:55:00+00:00  38803.9
```

df2:

```
time                       b_value      
2022-03-12 00:27:12+00:00  13
2022-03-12 00:29:26+00:00  14
2022-03-12 00:31:37+00:00  15                     
2022-03-12 23:19:38+00:00  16
2022-03-12 23:33:10+00:00  17
2022-03-12 23:41:52+00:00  18
```

`df1` contains full ranges of datetime indices with resolution `5 minutes` for a specific day; i.e. it has `24*60/5 = 288` records.

`df2` has lower indices than `df1` < 288 and they may all be different from indices in the `df1`.

The question is how we can merge these two data frames such that for each index of `df2`, the value of the nearest index to it from `df1` is used.

```
# Left outer join
desired_df = df2.merge(df1, on='time', how='left')
```

In other words how we can fill `NaN` values according to the values in another dataframe.

desired df:

```
time                       new_col      
2022-03-12 00:27:12+00:00  38882.1
2022-03-12 00:29:26+00:00  38882.1
2022-03-12 00:31:37+00:00  38882.1                     
2022-03-12 23:19:38+00:00  38965
2022-03-12 23:33:10+00:00  38965
2022-03-12 23:41:52+00:00  38933.2
```

Another idea is, for each index in `df2` we can compute the mean value between two consecutive indexes which are near that index. For eaxmple, the value correspond to the the index `2022-03-12 23:41:52+00:00` would be the mean of values of `2022-03-12 23:40:00+00:00` and `2022-03-12 23:45:00+00:00`.

---

After JonClements's comment, here is a pretty simple solution!

```
pd.merge_asof(left=df2, right=df1, on='time')
```

Comment: Might want to check out: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: @JonClements it works like a charm. Merci beaucoup

Answer (score 1):

You could try with [pandas interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

```
merged = df2.merge(df1, how='outer')
merged = pd.DataFrame(merged.set_index(pd.to_datetime(merged['time'])).drop('time', axis=1).sort_index()['p_value'])

merged['new_col'] = merged.apply(lambda x: x.interpolate('nearest'))
merged

Output:
                            p_value new_col
time        
2022-03-13 00:00:00+00:00   38743.7 38743.7
2022-03-13 00:05:00+00:00   38802.0 38802.0
2022-03-13 00:10:00+00:00   38842.0 38842.0
2022-03-13 00:15:00+00:00   38865.9 38865.9
2022-03-13 00:20:00+00:00   38882.1 38882.1
2022-03-13 00:27:12+00:00   NaN 38882.1
2022-03-13 00:29:26+00:00   NaN 38882.1
2022-03-13 00:31:37+00:00   NaN 38882.1
2022-03-13 23:19:38+00:00   NaN 38965.0
2022-03-13 23:33:10+00:00   NaN 38965.0
2022-03-13 23:35:00+00:00   38965.0 38965.0
2022-03-13 23:40:00+00:00   38933.2 38933.2
2022-03-13 23:41:52+00:00   NaN 38933.2
2022-03-13 23:45:00+00:00   38878.4 38878.4
2022-03-13 23:50:00+00:00   38861.3 38861.3
2022-03-13 23:55:00+00:00   38803.9 38803.9
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer +1. Your solution needs one more step to only keep the rows with `p_value` equals to `NaN`.